# How do I add a custom CHECK constraint on a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints, check-constraints

I am having trouble with this table

```
CREATE TABLE `Participants` (
  `meetid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pid` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meetid`,`pid`),
  CONSTRAINT `participants_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`meetid`) REFERENCES `Meetings` (`meetid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
  CONSTRAINT `participants_ibfk_2` CHECK (status IN ('a','d','u'))
  CONSTRAINT `participants_ibfk_3` CHECK (pid IN (SELECT name FROM Rooms) OR pid IN (SELECT userid FROM People))
);
```

I want to have a foreign key constraint, and that works. Then, I also want to add a constraint to the attribute `status` so it can only take the values 'a', 'd' and 'u'. It is not possible for me to set the field as `Enum` or `set`.

Can anyone tell me why this code does not work in MySQL?

Comment: As others mentioned before, check constaints were **finally** introduced with MySQL 8.0.16: https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting with version 8.0.16, MySQL has added support for CHECK constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE topic
ADD CONSTRAINT post_content_check
CHECK (
    CASE
        WHEN DTYPE = 'Post'
        THEN
            CASE
                WHEN content IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        ELSE 1
    END = 1
);
 
ALTER TABLE topic
ADD CONSTRAINT announcement_validUntil_check
CHECK (
    CASE
        WHEN DTYPE = 'Announcement'
        THEN
            CASE
                WHEN validUntil IS NOT NULL
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        ELSE 1
    END = 1
);
```

Previously, this was only available using BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE triggers:

```
CREATE
TRIGGER post_content_check BEFORE INSERT
ON topic
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.DTYPE = 'Post'
   THEN
       IF NEW.content IS NULL
       THEN
           signal sqlstate '45000'
           set message_text = 'Post content cannot be NULL';
       END IF;
   END IF;
END;
 
CREATE
TRIGGER post_content_update_check BEFORE UPDATE
ON topic
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.DTYPE = 'Post'
   THEN
       IF NEW.content IS NULL
       THEN
           signal sqlstate '45000'
           set message_text = 'Post content cannot be NULL';
       END IF;
   END IF;
END;
 
CREATE
TRIGGER announcement_validUntil_check BEFORE INSERT
ON topic
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.DTYPE = 'Announcement'
   THEN
       IF NEW.validUntil IS NULL
       THEN
           signal sqlstate '45000'
           set message_text = 'Announcement validUntil cannot be NULL';
       END IF;
   END IF;
END;
 
CREATE
TRIGGER announcement_validUntil_update_check BEFORE UPDATE
ON topic
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.DTYPE = 'Announcement'
   THEN
       IF NEW.validUntil IS NULL
       THEN
           signal sqlstate '45000'
           set message_text = 'Announcement validUntil cannot be NULL';
       END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 81):

`CHECK` constraints are not supported by MySQL. You can define them, but they do nothing (as of MySQL 5.7).

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> The `CHECK` clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

The workaround is to create [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/triggers.html), but they aren't the easiest thing to work with.

If you want an open-source RDBMS that supports `CHECK` constraints, try [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html). It's actually a very good database.

Comment: Thank you for the short and concrete answer

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why anybody uses MySQL anymore--"oops, sorry, we decided not to implement data integrity!". If you have any sort of control of your RDBMS, and you want open source, Postgres is The Way.

Comment: True that. 
MySQL is not a good choice for numerous reasons and this is one of them.

Comment: how to avoid minus value from the primary key? without `check(id>0)` function. using mysql 5.5

Comment: MariaDB 10.2 implements CHECK constraints.

Comment: This answer is no longer true for MySQL version 5.8.0.16 and forward.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: wasted 2 hours straight on this :/

Comment: MySQL 8.0.16 (April 2019) and later have support for `CHECK` constraints.

Answer (score 19):

I don't understand why nobody here has mentioned that **VIEW WITH CHECK OPTION** can be a good alternative to the **CHECK CONSTRAINT** in MySQL:

```
CREATE VIEW name_of_view AS SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE <condition> WITH [LOCAL | CASCADED] CHECK OPTION;
```

There is a doc on the MySQL site: [The View WITH CHECK OPTION Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-check-option.html)

```
DROP TABLE `Participants`;

CREATE TABLE `Participants` (
  `meetid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pid` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `status` char(1) DEFAULT NULL check (status IN ('a','d','u')),
  PRIMARY KEY (`meetid`,`pid`)
);

-- should work
INSERT INTO `Participants` VALUES (1,1,'a');
-- should fail but doesn't because table check is not implemented in MySQL
INSERT INTO `Participants` VALUES (2,1,'x');

DROP VIEW vParticipants;
CREATE VIEW vParticipants AS 
  SELECT * FROM Participants WHERE status IN ('a','d','u')
  WITH CHECK OPTION;

-- should work
INSERT INTO vParticipants VALUES (3,1,'a');
-- will fail because view uses a WITH CHECK OPTION
INSERT INTO vParticipants VALUES (4,1,'x');
```

**P.S.:** Keep in mind that your view should be updatable! See [MySQL Updatable Views](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-sql-updatable-views.aspx)
(thanks Romeo Sierra for clarification in comments).

Comment: "*I don't understand why nobody here has mentioned..*" pretty much because this is rather a workaround. But of course, this resolves the problem in a very very effective manner. All you need to do is just make sure that your **view is updatable**, and voila! problem is gone. +1 for that.

Answer (score 16):

Beside triggers, for simple constraints like the one you have:

```
CONSTRAINT `participants_ibfk_2` 
  CHECK status IN ('a','d','u')
```

you could use a `Foreign Key` from `status` to a Reference table (`ParticipantStatus` with 3 rows: `'a','d','u'` ):

```
CONSTRAINT ParticipantStatus_Participant_fk
  FOREIGN KEY (status)
    REFERENCES ParticipantStatus(status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of getting the checks you wanted quickly and easily:

```
drop database if exists gtest;

create database if not exists gtest;
use gtest;

create table users (
  user_id       integer unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  username      varchar(32) not null default '',
  password      varchar(64) not null default '',
  unique key ix_username (username)
) Engine=InnoDB auto_increment 10001;

create table owners (
  owner_id      integer unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  ownername     varchar(32) not null default '',
  unique key ix_ownername (ownername)
) Engine=InnoDB auto_increment 5001;

create table users_and_owners (
  id    integer unsigned not null primary key,
  name  varchar(32) not null default '',
  unique key ix_name(name)
) Engine=InnoDB;

create table p_status (
  a_status      char(1) not null primary key
) Engine=InnoDB;

create table people (
  person_id integer unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
  pid       integer unsigned not null,
  name      varchar(32) not null default '',
  status    char(1) not null,
  unique key ix_name (name),
  foreign key people_ibfk_001 (pid) references users_and_owners(id),
  foreign key people_ibfk_002 (status) references p_status (a_status)
) Engine=InnoDB;

create or replace view vw_users_and_owners as
select 
  user_id id,
  username name
from users
union
select 
  owner_id id,
  ownername name
from owners
order by id asc
;

create trigger newUser after insert on users for each row replace into users_and_owners select * from vw_users_and_owners;
create trigger newOwner after insert on owners for each row replace into users_and_owners select * from vw_users_and_owners;

insert into users ( username, password ) values
( 'fred Smith', password('fredSmith')),
( 'jack Sparrow', password('jackSparrow')),
( 'Jim Beam', password('JimBeam')),
( 'Ted Turner', password('TedTurner'))
;

insert into owners ( ownername ) values ( 'Tom Jones'),( 'Elvis Presley'),('Wally Lewis'),('Ted Turner');

insert into people (pid, name, status) values ( 5001, 'Tom Jones', 1),(10002,'jack Sparrow',1),(5002,'Elvis Presley',1);
```