# Unique constraint that check two columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint

I would like to add a unicity constraint on my MySQL table. This table contains four columns :

```
ID | NAME | ADDRESS1 | ADDRESS2
```

This constraint must check that for a new row, the new `address1` and `address2` are not contained either in `ADDRESS1` nor `ADDRESS2`.

Example :

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2) values ('A', 'B'); -- OK
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2) values ('C', 'D'); -- OK
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2) values ('E', 'A'); -- Fails because A exists in ADDRESS1
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2) values ('D', 'F'); -- Fails because D exists in ADDRESS2
```

Is there a way to define a such constraint ?

Comment: your design is bad for addresses (use separate table for them) anyway you can use unique indices

Comment: I know the design could be way better. But unfortunately I cannot change it, that is why I am looking for a such constraint.

Comment: You could always create a trigger. I don't believe MySQL has CHECK constraints, which would be ideal here.

Comment: Yes actually the CHECK constraints exist but are ignored.

Comment: @dounyy Haha - CHECK exists, but does nothing?

Comment: @Nicarus The manual says it is ignored... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522026/how-do-i-add-a-check-constratint-to-a-table?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @dounyy What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @dounyy Can you please show exact table schema e.g. as a result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`. I'm particularly interested in `NOT NULL` constraints on any of your columns to give you a solution with a trigger.

Comment: @peterm `NAME` and `ADDRESS1` are unique and not null. `ADDRESS2` is unique but can be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `BEFORE` trigger this way

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_mytable
BEFORE INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.address1 = IF(EXISTS
     (
       SELECT * 
        FROM mytable 
       WHERE address1 IN(NEW.address1, NEW.address2) 
          OR address2 IN(NEW.address1, NEW.address2)
     ), NULL, NEW.address1);
```

**Note:** Since you're using a MySQL version that lacks `SIGNAL` the trick is to violate `NOT NULL` constraint on one of the columns when rows with the same address have been found.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad7ae5/1)** demo. Uncomment one of the last insert statements and click `Build Schema`. These inserts won't succeed.

Comment: Well, that is a solution that fit my needs, the only little thing is that violating the `NOT NULL` constraint returns an error message which is not very appropriate. I am going to look for a way to define a custom one.

Comment: I finally decided to manage this unicity inside my Java code. That is easier for me, and it is, to my point of view, better than using a workaround/hack to replace a feature that is not supported by my version of MySQL.
However, I accept your answer, since it could have helped me, and will probably help some other people.
Thank you a lot.