# How to store a sequence of digits (or sequence of characters from some other set)?

Tags: mysql, sql, digit, alphabet

I want to save some sequence of digits, which may be a number (eg 12345, 1230) or not (eg 00123, 0120). Which type of column is the most effective (by memory, by indexing speed) for that purpose?

Also, I need to store strings of characters from specially defined alphabet (eg "digits and comma" or "digits and english letters and dots and commas"). How to effectively do this?

Can I set limits on `CHAR`/`VARCHAR` type of a column to reduce the memory size it takes?

Answer (score 0):

This is no different from any string column which implies varchar/text type.

`VARCHAR(n)` takes care of storage dynamically.

[Reference here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html).

---

For constraining allowed symbols you could use CHECK constraints, but they don't work in MySQL so a workaround is to use trigger and define accepted characters there. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522026/how-do-i-add-a-check-constratint-to-a-table)
You could use `REGEXP` function to define your allowed alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

**For sql you can go with**

> varchar() and if your using POSTgreSQL you can make use of something
>   known as citext