# having trouble in ignore a value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a table where a column can't contain the value `0` have tried many times but its not working why?

The queries i have tried:

```
create tale t_name(a int(11) not null check(a<>0));
```

this query is ok but the column a is still taking the value `0` why?

Comment: MySQL silently ignores CHECK constraints, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working

Comment: are you using mysql? If so, which version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7522055/5602069

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a check constraint to a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522026/how-do-i-add-a-check-constraint-to-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that though MYSQL accepts CHECK clause in create table, but it silently ignores CHECK clause. Check the link [MySQL trigger](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-check-constraint/) for workaround.

Comment: thats ok but how we can ignore the 0 for  a particular column value for a sql or mysql table?