# How to check if a word is in a set of allowed words during INSERT INTO table VALUES (....)?

Tags: mysql

Obviously that would happen during the creation of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(
    e_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    e_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    type CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT type CHECK (type IN ('FOH, 'BOH', 'TCH', 'SHF', 'KSH', 'MOM', 'SIS')),
    PRIMARY KEY (e_id)
);
```

mysql doesn't let this work and I'm not sure how to do it. Basically, type is supposed to be a word only from one of the seven words ('FOH', 'BOH', ... etc).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a separate lookup table for your allowed words with a foreign key in your Employees table?  This would be more maintainable and allow for new allowed words to be added in future.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a custom CHECK constraint on a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522026/how-do-i-add-a-custom-check-constraint-on-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the `CONSTRAINT`:

```
type CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
CHECK (type IN ('FOH, 'BOH', 'TCH', 'SHF', 'KSH', 'MOM', 'SIS'))
```

or by changing the `CONSTRAINT` name

```
type CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT type2 CHECK (type IN ('FOH, 'BOH', 'TCH', 'SHF', 'KSH', 'MOM', 'SIS'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems absolutely correct except a minor correction for specifying the constraint name -

```
CREATE TABLE Employees(
    e_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    e_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    type CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT type_values CHECK (type IN ('FOH', 'BOH', 'TCH', 'SHF', 'KSH', 'MOM', 'SIS')),
    PRIMARY KEY (e_id)
);
```

However MySQL doesn't support CHECK constraint yet. There is some workaround for it. Please check below link for details -

[How do I add a custom CHECK constraint on a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522026/how-do-i-add-a-custom-check-constraint-on-a-mysql-table)

Comment: MySQL has started supporting [CHECK constraint, since version 8.0.16](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html)